# Should self answered question based on experience be encouraged?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

Sometimes, I may encounter some problems, which doesn't have an answer in stackoverflow yet.

And finally I found the solution, maybe through reading docs or other way?

Is posting both such question and answer by myself be encouraged?

---

More over, for example, like this question I asked today: [rendering image for preview from selected file in file input tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585189/rendering-image-for-preview-from-selected-file-in-file-input-tag). So how can I get repulation benefit on it?

Comment: It is. See  Self-Learner badge. Athough I think you may accept someone elses answer if provided and correct, not necessary yours.

Comment: Just like this question I asked today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585189/rendering-image-for-preview-from-selected-file-in-file-input-tag. So how can I get repulation benefit on it?

Comment: @fish_ball You'll soon realize reputation on StackOverflow isn't everything ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it states on the Ask Question page, it's absolutely encouraged:

> Answer your own question – [share your knowledge, Q&A-style](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

> It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you’re on Jeopardy! — phrase it in the form of a question.
>
> To be crystal clear, **it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is *explicitly* encouraged.**

Comment: to the extent that its bloody annoying to see a question with a comment under it 'don't worry i figured it out' and no bloody answer.

Comment: so if encouraged, how to get benefit from it?

Comment: @fish_ball Just write a good question and good answer and if they're helpful you'll get upvotes for both.